# Displaying comments using django_comments

Tags: django, comments, django-comments

I have

1. installed `django_comments`
2. put it in INSTALLED_APPS field in `settings.py`
3. have defined `SITE_ID = 1`
4. enabled the sites framework
5. put `url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls'))` in `urls.py`
6. have written `{% load comments %}` in `home.html`

But I still can't see any comments loading in my home page.
What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit your question and show your relevant settings. Also, have you defined a `SITE_ID`?

Comment: @rnevius What other settings?

Comment: I'm just saying to actually show your settings file here. There may be a misconfiguration. Also, `{% load comments %}` doesn't actually *show* comments...it just loads them. You need to use `{% render_comment_list for [object] %}` to actually show them (replacing `[object]` with your model name.)

Comment: {%load comments %} is this assignment tag.please paste your code here,cant say anything from this description

Comment: @rnevius: Thanks, I wasn't rendering the comments just loading them. However, I am still facing issue, I asked my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026483/using-django-comments-but-getting-queryset-object-has-no-attribute-meta). Please see that.

Comment: @KamalBanga, I added my comment as an answer. I'll check out your other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% load comments %}` doesn't actually show comments...it just loads them. You need to use `{% render_comment_list for [object] %}` to actually show them (replacing `[object]` with your model name.)

Read more in the section on displaying comments [in the docs](http://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#displaying-comments).