# Using django_comments but getting 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, comments, django-comments, django-errors

My django project named `comments` is [here](https://github.com/kamalbanga/comments). It has an app `comms` which is there to display comments using `django_comments`.

I have

1. installed `django_comments`
2. put it in INSTALLED_APPS field in `settings.py`
3. have defined `SITE_ID = 1`
4. enabled the sites framework
5. put `url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls'))` in `urls.py`

But [this template](https://github.com/kamalbanga/comments/blob/master/comms/home.html) file is giving me this error:

> AttributeError at /
>
> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your home.html to something like:

```
{% load comments %}
<html>
    {% for entry in categ %}
        {% get_comment_count for entry as comment_count %}
        {% render_comment_list for entry %}
    {% empty %}
        <p> categ not present </p>
    {% endfor %}
</html>
```

As I understand the template tags take an object as parameter, but you have provided the Queryset(Category.objects.all()).

Not tested the code, but something similar should work.

Comment: The example could be seen here: http://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html

Comment: I get blank page in home when I put an element in `categ` (so that it's not empty).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you, can you explain a bit.

Comment: I get a blank home page. I don't get any comments field.

Comment: So how do I enter any comment?

Comment: This view is just to display the comments list for an object, to add comments you'll need to add a separate view, or using the Django Admin Interface.